# Как понимать «алгоритмы групповых решений в задачах распознавания образов»?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание-образов

Дали тему для дипломной работы: **"Разработка алгоритмов групповых решений в задачах распознавания образов"**.
 
Я лично сам понимаю, что такое непосредственно распознавание образов, имею опыт решения различных задач с помощью машинного обучения. Но не совсем понимаю, что подразумевают в данном случае *"алгоритмы групповых решений"*. Кто понимает, что это такое подскажите пожалуйста, как это понимать. Что собой представляют *групповые решения*? Гуглить пробовал, не сильно помогло. Информации совсем не много. Или может быть это просто не совсем неудачная формулировка темы.

Comment: Может лучше спросить у научного руководителя / руководителя диплома?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо имеется в виду композиция алгоритмов машинного обучения. То что по-английски называется ensemble classifiers.

Основная идея в том, что одна голова - хорошо, а две (или больше) - лучше. Если у вас есть несколько классификаторов, ошибки которых статистически независимы, то объединив их усилия можно улучшить точность классификации. Самые распространенные варианты композиции классификаторов это бэггинг (bagging) и бустинг (boosting).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.